# Prolog. How to output solution like Yes or No

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I tried to solve the problem of a point belongs to the area. As a result, I need to get an answer: if a point belongs to the area or not.
Coordinates of the point entered by the user from the keyboard. When I try to transfer the coordinates of the point directly in a rule: `belongsTo (1,1).` I get the desired result (yes or no), but when I enter the coordinates with the keyboard

```
write ("Input X:"), readreal (X),
write ("Input Y:"), readreal (Y),
belongsTo (X, Y).
```

Then the answer will be 'no solutions' or just '2 solutions' (X = 0, Y = 0, X = 0, Y = 0, if you pass the point (0,0))

Here's the code completely:

```
PREDICATES
    square(real,real)
    semicircle(real,real)
    belongsTo(real,real)
CLAUSES
    square(X,Y):-
        X>=-1,X<=0,
        Y>=-1,Y<=0.

    semicircle(X,Y):-
        X>=0,Y>=0,
        X*X+Y*Y<=1.

    belongsTo(X,Y):-
        square(X,Y);
        semicircle(X,Y),!.
GOAL
    write("Input X: "), readreal(X),
    write("Input Y: "), readreal(Y),
    belongsTo(X,Y).
```

As a result I need to get a solution like YES(if the point belongs to the area) or NO.

Comment: Does Visual Prolog allow a space between a functor name and the left parenthesis introducing its arguments? *E.g.*, is `readreal (X)` valid? Or should it be `readreal(X)` to avoid error?

Comment: The way `semicircle` is currently defined, it is really only checking for a *quadrant* (non-negative `X` and non-negative `Y`), not a `semicircle`. You need to show exactly what you entered at the keyboard which gave unexpected results.

Comment: both `readreal (X)` and `readreal(X)` are valid/

Comment: OK, in SWI Prolog the space doesn't work, which is why I asked.

Comment: why u think, that `semicircle` checking only quadrant. It verifies that the point is in 1  quadrant and in a semicircle with a radius of R=1 and the center A=(x0,y0)=(0,0). Or I am wrong?

Comment: here is pictude of areas http://imgur.com/mn5nPZ3

Comment: Sorry, our firewall won't let me access that. But since your circle is centered at `(0, 0)`, then the quadrants would be have coordinates with signs in the following areas: `(+, +)`, `(+, -)`, `(-, -)`, and `(-, +)` (and 0 allowed in each coordinate). Your `semicircle` is just the `(+, +)` quadrant (you are requiring `X >= 0` *and* `Y >= 0`). A semicircle would be, for example, would be *only* `X >= 0` or *only* `Y >= 0`, in conjunction with `X*X + Y*Y <= 1`.

Comment: thank you, but the question was slightly different. How do I get an answer Yes(if the point belongs to the area) or No to the console? Now I get the following response when X = 0 and Y = 0: `X=0, Y=0 X=0 Y=0 2 Solutions`

Comment: I know the question is different. I was just pointing out a flaw. I did indicate, *You need to show exactly what you entered at the keyboard which gave unexpected results* but I haven't seen that yet. You are saying what you want for a response, but a response to what kind of query?

Comment: ok, I will give a full statement of the task. "Determine if the point belongs to the shaded area. Coordinates of the point entered by the user from the keyboard."

Comment: *You need to show exactly what you entered at the keyboard which gave unexpected results*. You showed the code that failed (with the `readreal` statements) but what numbers did you give it? Do any numbers actually succeed when entered this way? If they work with direct query `belongsTo(1,1)` for example, but not when prompted with `readreal` then there's something wrong with how they're being entered.

Comment: I answered you. When I use the `belongsTo(1,1)` it returns "No" in console (this is the correct result), but when im using `readreal(X)` (I enter from the keyboard 1) and `readreal(Y)` (I enter from the keyboard 1) and then `belongsTo(X,Y)` it returns just "No Solution". Expected just simply "No". Another example: When I use the `belongsTo(0,0)` it returns "Yes" in console (this is the correct result), but when im using `readreal(X)` (I enter from the keyboard 0) and `readreal(Y)` (I enter from the keyboard 0) and then `belongsTo(X,Y)` it returns `X=0, Y=0 X=0, Y=0 2 Solutions`. Expected "Yes"

Comment: I see. I don't have Visual Prolog, so I'm not sure I can sort that out. It's something about how the `readreal(X)` and `readreal(Y)` are working. What happens if you type in at the keyboard, `0.5` and `0.5` when prompted?

Comment: it returns `X=0.5, Y=0.5 1 Solution`, but i need simply `Yes`

Comment: It's returning the `X` and `Y` results because the expression, `readreal(X), ...` has `X` and `Y` as variables. Did you try making a predicate, `readuser :- write('Input X: '), readreal(X), write('Input Y: '), readreal(Y), belongsTo(X, Y).` and then type in `readuser.`? That might avoid the extra output. I think entering 1 and 1 might be failing here if Visual Prolog is reading them in as real numbers with a little inaccuracy (*e.g.*, 1.000000000001). Just a theory... And you get `(0, 0)` twice because it succeeds in BOTH the quarter circle (:)) and the square. So it succeeds twice.

Comment: It's working now. I am very grateful for your help and your patience. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the prompting method:

```
write("Input X:"), readreal(X),
write("Input Y:"), readreal(Y),
belongsTo(X, Y).
```

Prolog will display the values of `X` and `Y` along with the solution (yes or no) because these variables appear explicitly in your query. Any variables in your query it assumes you want to see the results of. If you just want to see yes or no, then you can make a predicate:

```
readuser :-
    write("Input X:"), readreal(X),
    write("Input Y:"), readreal(Y),
    belongsTo(X, Y).
```

And then just query `readuser`. You'll then just get yes or no without the values of `X` and `Y` displayed.

As far as the different results, if you enter `0` and `0` for `X` and `Y`, this input will succeed *twice*: once for `semicircle` and once for `square`. Prolog faithfully finds both successful results.

When you are entering 1 and 1 and reading them as "real", I am suspecting that the internal representation is getting a little bit of floating point accuracy issue and internally becoming something like, `1.000000001` and these will fail both the `semicircle` and `square` tests.

As an aside, the `semicircle` is testing for the non-negative `X` and non-negative `Y` quadrant, not really a semicircle. Actual `semicircle` checks would be constraining just *one* of the coordinates in conjunction with `X*X + Y*Y <= 1`, *e.g.*, `X >= 0, X*X + Y*Y <= 1` would be the upper right and lower right quadrants of the semicircle.